# Cannot update R package from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, conda, anaconda3

Scenario started where I attempt to install & load MCMCpack and receive the following:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'MCMCpack' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace 'Rcpp' 1.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.3 is required
```

However I am unable to get Rcpp to update from v1.0.1.
I've attempted:

1. install.packages("Rcpp_1.0.3.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
   library("Rcpp")

This results in:

```
***Warning message in install.packages("Rcpp_1.0.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source"):
"installation of package 'Rcpp_1.0.3.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status"***
```

(have also tried rcpp v 1.0.6 with same results)

2. Executing the following from the Anaconda prompt:

   **conda install -c r r-rcpp**

This results in:

```
# All requested packages already installed.
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: The key is `'Rcpp' 1.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.3 is required`. You need to start a 'plain' R session without _any_ packages, then in that install Rcpp.  On the command-line this might be `R --vanilla` (among other choices); it could also be a session image that is reloaded -- we cannot tell from here.  I also cannot heko you with Anaconda though others might.

Comment: I tried your recommendation but unfortunately it did not work in Jupyter.  It works fine in R studio so it seems to have something to do with anaconda navigator &/or Jupyter.  I'm not very familiar with environment setup but any other suggestions would be great. I do need to get it up & running in Jupyter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using the [`conda` `r` channel for R and R packages](https://anaconda.org/r/r). It is woefully out of date. At the time of writing this remark, the channel is serving up R 3.6.0.

A better approach would be to use the `conda-forge` channel, e.g.

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge r-rcpp
```

The `conda-forge` channel should give [R 4.1](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r) and [Rcpp 1.0.6](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-rcpp)

Though, the best approach is to ditch `conda` completely for *R*.

Comment: Even better, specify the end packages OP actually uses (`r-mcmcpack`) and let those determine the correct versions for dependencies. I also disagree with the unsolicited opinion here about "*the best approach*": if one is diligent about using Conda-only packages (no `install.packages`), things run perfectly fine, and it provides a reasonable workflow for switching project-specific R environments.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you.